# Using Silverlight or Flash to detect USB Devices on Client Machine and Run them

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, flash

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` in my application,I have a requirement where I need to access USB devices of client computer and run one of them.It is ok if the user has right to allow it or not.I need to know whether it is possible at all from browser.If yes what can be used here `flash` or `silverlight`.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, "can I use *web-client* technology running in browser sandbox for system programming". No, you can't. Neither Flash nor Silverlight can detect or run anything from USB devices. You need *desktop* technology like **Adobe AIR** or **Microsoft WPF** to do that.
Update:
If you really need to do something from browser that browser can't do, there is a way. Install helper application on user machine and control it from browser app via local network. I did it once, so it's possible. If you go this way, use what you like most - both Flash and Silverlight can do this.

Comment: http://sblakemore.com/blog/post/Silverlight-4-COM-Automation-e28093-Taking-photos-with-a-DSLR-using-Windows-Image-Acquisition.aspx is it desktop based

Comment: Please read carefully: "COM automation in Silverlight requires that the application is running Out-Of-Browser". That's it. No browser app, be it flash or SL, is going to activate your USB devices (for the good.)